# How to check if a string contains ALL of required characters in php

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a string contains letters A, B, and C and nothing else. Is there a shorthand way of doing this using `preg_match`?

To give an example of what I want, the check should return

```
ABC //TRUE
AABC //TRUE
ABBCC //TRUE
ABCD //FALSE
```

Thus, a string **MUST** contain *A*, *B*, and *C* at least once, and no other characters.

Comment: What about `CAB`?

Comment: CAB is fine, order does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match A, B and C, in any order, *at least* one time, you can use this regular expression:

```
/^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)([a-c])+$/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0fhVb/1)

However, I think you can achieve this without regular expressions. Make a function that takes as an argument a list of characters to check, and a string. For each character, first check if it's contained in the string. If any isn't, return `false`. If they're all there, delete them from the string. Now, if the string is empty, then there are no other characters, so you can return `true`, and `false` otherwise:

```
<?php
function checkCharacters($list, $string) {
    foreach ($list as $letter) {
        if (stripos($string, $letter) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        $string = str_ireplace($letter, "", $string);
    }
    return empty($string);
}
$list = ["A", "B", "C"];
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "ABC")).PHP_EOL; // true
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "AABC")).PHP_EOL; // true
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "ABBCC")).PHP_EOL; // true
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "ABCD")).PHP_EOL; // false
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "BAC")).PHP_EOL; // true
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "ABACBCBACB")).PHP_EOL; // true
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "AB")).PHP_EOL; // false
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "AC")).PHP_EOL; // false
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "A")).PHP_EOL; // false
var_dump(checkCharacters($list, "abc")).PHP_EOL; // true
```

This is, just in case, case insensitive, so it will accept `a`, `b` and `c` as well.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sI94I)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, you can do it with with `preg_match`...

```
if (!preg_match("/^[ABC]+$/",$yourtext)) {
   echo 'This string has other characters.';   
} else {
   echo 'This string only has A,B and C.';
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function str_alphabet($string, array $alphabet) {
    $counts = array_count_values(str_split($string));

    sort($alphabet);
    ksort($counts);

    return array_keys($counts) === $alphabet;
}
```

This will return true if `$string` contains each letter of the provided `$alphabet` array at least once, and no other characters.

Example usage:

```
str_alphabet('ABACBABCABCABCA', ['A', 'B', 'C']); // true
str_alphabet('ABCD', ['A', 'B', 'C']); // false
```